# Как правильно передавать данные вещественного типа между формами?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, мне нужно передать данные вещественного типа с одного шаблона в другой.
Для этого я создала класс с константами:

```
public class Constans {
    public static final String DATE_KEY = "date_key";
    public static final float HEIGHT_KEY = Float.parseFloat("height_key");
    public static final float WEIGHT_KEY = Float.parseFloat("weight_key");
}
```

Далее мне необходимо данные передать с помощью intent:

```
public void onAdapterItemClicked(int position) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(Constans.DATE_KEY,listParameter.get(position).getDate());
    i.putExtra(Constans.HEIGHT_KEY, listParameter.get(position).getHeight());
    i.putExtra(Constans.WEIGHT_KEY,listParameter.get(position).getWeight());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

И в моем активити выдаЮ данные следующим методом:

```
private void getMyIntent()
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i != null)
    {
        if(i.getStringExtra(DATE_KEY) != null)
        {
            mDisplayDate.setText(i.getStringExtra(Constans.DATE_KEY));

            edHeight.setText(i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(Constans.HEIGHT_KEY)));
            edWeight.setText(i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(Constans.WEIGHT_KEY)));
```

}
В методе я преобразовала значения вещественного типа в строку с помощью String.valueOf.
А как это сделать в onAdapterItemClicked ума не приложу. Подскажите, какую конструкцию здесь необходимо использовать?

Comment: Кажется, вы пытаетесь за раз решить сразу 3 задачи. Передача значений между активити, вычисление размеров вьюх в пикселях, запуск активити по клику. А тут принято один вопрос за раз задавать. Определитесь с чем именно у вас сложности. Пока что мало что понятно, разве что `float WEIGHT_KEY = Float.parseFloat("weight_key");` выглядит как ошибка. По идее должно исключение выкидывать.

Comment: Проблема у меня именно в строке i.putExtra(Constans.HEIGHT_KEY, listParameter.get(position).getHeight());
            i.putExtra(Constans.WEIGHT_KEY,listParameter.get(position).getWeight());

Comment: Надо обязательно описывать - какая проблема. Предположу, что у вас тут падает. В этом случае, надо заменить, наверное, `float WEIGHT_KEY = Float.parseFloat("weight_key");` на `String WEIGHT_KEY = "weight_key";`

Comment: А если у меня значение потом под этим ключик будут вещественного типа? Н-мер 52.5; Я пробовала через String идти. Ошибки нет, но данные в форме не выводятся. Просто пустые поля.

Comment: Полагаю вам нужно это `edHeight.setText(String.valueOf(i.getFloatExtra(Constans.HEIGHT_KEY, 0F)));` (тоже самое для edWeight) в вашем `getMyIntent` и в Constans  переделать на `public static final String HEIGHT_KEY = "height_key";` и для `WEIGHT_KEY` тоже самое

Comment: Спасибо большое!
До этого пробовала точно так же, ноне проставляла значение defaultValue - 0.
Сейчас прописала,  данные выводятся. Еще раз спасибо)